# "cool dissenters"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I uploaded <strike>a</strike> some music <strike>at</strike> to a site.

It was Billy Joel's work.

And I got a reply saying,

> It’s one of those songs that a LOT of people hate on, simply because it’s so poppy and unlike a lot of Joel’s best work. Honestly I think some people **just like to hate to be cool dissenters.**

And I expressed astonishment <strike>to</strike> at his reply because Billy Joel is so famous.

What does the bold part mean?

Comment: It's irrelevant how famous Billy Joel is. What's being ***dissented*** from *(**disagreed with**)* is the idea that everyone should ***like*** Joel's work. And some people think it's "cool" (fashionable, sophisticated) to ***dislike*** it so much that they could be described as ***hating*** (Joel himself, ***or*** his musical works, it makes no difference here).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "cool dissenter" is a person who deliberately professes to hold a non-mainstream view because they think this makes them somehow "better" than the non-thinking people who follow the latest trend.

A "cool dissenter" may in fact secretly actually hold the same view that he or she professes not to hold.

As for me, I have no time for Billy Joel whatsoever. I do everything I can to avoid having to listen to his bland, empty, pointless pap.

Comment: >As for me, I have no time for Billy Joel whatsoever. I do everything I can to avoid having to listen to his bland, empty, pointless pap.     Okay....

Comment: Lol. When you say "pap", everything became clear about "dissenter".

Comment: Unlike many other famous entertainers who've been [lampooned by Family Guy,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Family_Guy_guest_stars) Billy Joel never actually did the voiceovers for his appearances. Probably because he didn't approve of them (as I recall from more than one appearance of Joel's cartoon likeness there, Family Guy has been pretty merciless towards his musical style! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Hm...since I've never watched Family Guys before, so I can't say anymore, but I hope I could I understand. Thank you.

Comment: *Some people just like "hating on" people like Billy Joel, because they think it's "cool" not to like his style*. I'm one of those people - I can stand about 10 seconds of Family Guy mocking Joel, but after that it gets on my nerves because the extent to which I ***dislike*** (and thus don't want to hear) Joel's mindless pap exceeds the extent to which I find it ***amusing*** for FG to poke fun at it!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Hahahah Got it,

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Asians' simply don't care sorry. Joel's perfect lists are on the Karaoke club always there anyways.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Call me a "cool dissenter" if you like, but I really don't care for Family Guy. I watched a few episodes and was mildly amused, but since then I have decided I would rather spend that time doing something else. :-)